# Does 2 Corinthians 9:6-7 contain an allusion to Sirach 35:10-13?

Tags: 2-corinthians, sirach, intertextuality

2 Corinthians 9:6-7 reads (ESV):

> The point is this: whoever sows sparingly will also reap sparingly, and whoever sows bountifully will also reap bountifully. Each one must give as he has decided in his heart, not reluctantly or under compulsion, for God loves a cheerful giver.

Sirach 35:10-13 reads (NRSV):

```
Be generous when you worship the Lord,
    and do not stint the first fruits of your hands.
With every gift show a cheerful face,
    and dedicate your tithe with gladness.
Give to the Most High as he has given to you,
    and as generously as you can afford.
For the Lord is the one who repays,
    and he will repay you sevenfold.
```

How likely is it that Paul's words in 2 Corinthians 9:6-7 were written with an eye to Sirach 35:10-13?

Quotations from any previous scholarship on this question would be much appreciated as part of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would seem so.  Paul also may have had the Proverbs and Tobit in mind as well:

> **Proverbs 22:8** (LXX)
>
> > *He who sows worthless things will reap evil things, And bring to an end the plague of his works.*
> >
> > *God blesses a cheerful man and a giver, And he will bring to an end the vanity of his works.*
>
> ---
>
> **Tobit 4:7**
>
> > *Do almsgiving from your possessions to all who do righteousness. When you do almsgiving, do not let your eye be envious.*
> >
> > *Do not turn your face away from any poor man, so the face of God will
> >     not be turned away from you.*

All of the above may also be a reflection of Exodus 25:2:

> *Speak to the children of Israel, that they take first fruits from everyone who gives it willingly from the heart.*

[Note:  all Old Testament quotations taken from the *Orthodox Study Bible* Septuagint translation]